# C# Visual studio 2010 Bilingual basic form

Tags: c#, winforms, internationalization, arabic, right-to-left

I am a beginner in C# using Visual Studio 2010 and I am trying to make a small bilingual .cs form in Visual Studio 2010.

Could anyone please help me on the code for to get the alignment when clicked on Arabic and content should start from right side (as Arabic starts from right) and followed by text boxes ... i.e. starting from right side Arabic content followed by text boxes when clicked on Arabic radio button ... I hope am clear.  Here is the code which I used in the below image:

[image: code used]

Sorry for the format I used to post my question.

The CS form in English and Arabic in one form which has Name and location followed by text boxes as in below image:

[image: .CS form in English and arabic in one form which has Name and location followed by text boxes as in below image link]

Comment: If you can use WPF. I know right-to-left. It's nearly impossible in windows forms and readily available in WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to our discussion in comments you can use WPF. Please see [this](http://www.wpftutorial.net/HelloWPF.html) article and start your first application. Then add the following line in your window parameters to see it right to left:

```
<Window ...
    FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <!--Your layout and controls-->
</Window>
```

You can also add or remove the flow direction in code or even add it as a string in resource file to include it dynamically. I use this method all the time and it's perfect.